# Is it possible to query the current power supply voltages from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wmi, bios

At [this link](http://www.chabotcollege.edu/faculty/netacad/prot/ITE/course/module3/3.2.2.4/3.2.2.4.html) there's a screen where the BIOS shows the current system voltages on the 3.3V, 5V, and 12V lines. I know that I can access the CPU voltage using WMI's `Win32_Process`. Is there an equivalent for power supply voltage? Any programmatic or command line method would be acceptable.

[image: alternate image]